# can someone help me to include aces into my blackjack program

Tags: vb.net, blackjack

I have been trying to create a simple blackjack game where the user picks cards and decides whether to hit or stick and if their cards go above 21 they lose. however i do not know how to add in aces so that the program will choose whether the ace will be a 1 or an 11.
please help
this is my code

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim cards(4, 13) As Integer

    Dim value As Integer
    Dim value2 As Integer
    Dim royal As String
    Dim suit As String
    Dim card1 As Integer
    Dim card2 As Integer
    Dim card3 As Integer
    Dim card4 As Integer
    Dim card5 As Integer
    Dim card6 As Integer
    Dim card7 As Integer
    Dim answer As String
    Dim total As Integer

    Randomize()
    value = (3 * Rnd()) + 1
    value2 = (11 * Rnd()) + 1

    'suits: 1= hearts
    '2= diamonds
    '3=spades
    '4=clubs
    cards(1, 1) = 2
    cards(2, 1) = 2
    cards(3, 1) = 2
    cards(4, 1) = 2
    cards(1, 2) = 3
    cards(2, 2) = 3
    cards(3, 2) = 3
    cards(4, 2) = 3
    cards(1, 3) = 4
    cards(2, 3) = 4
    cards(3, 3) = 4
    cards(4, 3) = 4
    cards(1, 4) = 5
    cards(2, 4) = 5
    cards(3, 4) = 5
    cards(4, 4) = 5
    cards(1, 5) = 6
    cards(2, 5) = 6
    cards(3, 5) = 6
    cards(4, 5) = 6
    cards(1, 6) = 7
    cards(2, 6) = 7
    cards(3, 6) = 7
    cards(4, 6) = 7
    cards(1, 7) = 8
    cards(2, 7) = 8
    cards(3, 7) = 8
    cards(4, 7) = 8
    cards(1, 8) = 9
    cards(2, 8) = 9
    cards(3, 8) = 9
    cards(4, 8) = 9
    cards(1, 9) = 10
    cards(2, 9) = 10
    cards(3, 9) = 10
    cards(4, 9) = 10
    'jacks
    cards(1, 10) = 10
    cards(2, 10) = 10
    cards(3, 10) = 10
    cards(4, 10) = 10
    'queens
    cards(1, 11) = 10
    cards(2, 11) = 10
    cards(3, 11) = 10
    cards(4, 11) = 10
    'kings
    cards(1, 12) = 10
    cards(2, 12) = 10
    cards(3, 12) = 10
    cards(4, 12) = 10



    If value2 = 1 Then
        royal = "2"
    ElseIf value2 = 2 Then
        royal = "3"
    ElseIf value2 = 3 Then
        royal = "4"
    ElseIf value2 = 4 Then
        royal = "5"
    ElseIf value2 = 5 Then
        royal = "6"
    ElseIf value2 = 6 Then
        royal = "7"
    ElseIf value2 = 7 Then
        royal = "8"
    ElseIf value2 = 8 Then
        royal = "9"
    ElseIf value2 = 9 Then
        royal = "10"
    ElseIf value2 = 10 Then
        royal = "jack"
    ElseIf value2 = 11 Then
        royal = "queen"
    ElseIf value2 = 12 Then
        royal = "king"


    End If

    If value = 1 Then
        suit = "hearts"
    ElseIf value = 2 Then
        suit = "diamonds"
    ElseIf value = 3 Then
        suit = "spades"
    ElseIf value = 4 Then
        suit = "clubs"

    End If
    Console.WriteLine("your first card is the {0} of {1}", royal, suit)
    card1 = cards(value, value2)

    value = (3 * Rnd()) + 1
    value2 = (11 * Rnd()) + 1
    If value2 = 1 Then
        royal = "2"
    ElseIf value2 = 2 Then
        royal = "3"
    ElseIf value2 = 3 Then
        royal = "4"
    ElseIf value2 = 4 Then
        royal = "5"
    ElseIf value2 = 5 Then
        royal = "6"
    ElseIf value2 = 6 Then
        royal = "7"
    ElseIf value2 = 7 Then
        royal = "8"
    ElseIf value2 = 8 Then
        royal = "9"
    ElseIf value2 = 9 Then
        royal = "10"
    ElseIf value2 = 10 Then
        royal = "jack"
    ElseIf value2 = 11 Then
        royal = "queen"
    ElseIf value2 = 12 Then
        royal = "king"
    End If
    If value = 1 Then
        suit = "hearts"
    ElseIf value = 2 Then
        suit = "diamonds"
    ElseIf value = 3 Then
        suit = "spades"
    ElseIf value = 4 Then
        suit = "clubs"
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("your second card is the {0} of {1}", royal, suit)
    card2 = cards(value, value2)
    Console.ReadKey()
    total = card1 + card2
    If total > 21 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You lose")
        Console.ReadLine()
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to hit or stick?")
        answer = Console.ReadLine
        If answer = "hit" Then
            value = (3 * Rnd()) + 1
            value2 = (11 * Rnd()) + 1
            If value2 = 1 Then
                royal = "2"
            ElseIf value2 = 2 Then
                royal = "3"
            ElseIf value2 = 3 Then
                royal = "4"
            ElseIf value2 = 4 Then
                royal = "5"
            ElseIf value2 = 5 Then
                royal = "6"
            ElseIf value2 = 6 Then
                royal = "7"
            ElseIf value2 = 7 Then
                royal = "8"
            ElseIf value2 = 8 Then
                royal = "9"
            ElseIf value2 = 9 Then
                royal = "10"
            ElseIf value2 = 10 Then
                royal = "jack"
            ElseIf value2 = 11 Then
                royal = "queen"
            ElseIf value2 = 12 Then
                royal = "king"
            End If
            If value = 1 Then
                suit = "hearts"
            ElseIf value = 2 Then
                suit = "diamonds"
            ElseIf value = 3 Then
                suit = "spades"
            ElseIf value = 4 Then
                suit = "clubs"
            End If
            Console.WriteLine("your card is the {0} of {1}", royal, suit)
            card3 = cards(value, value2)
            Console.ReadKey()
            total = card1 + card2 + card3
            If total > 21 Then
                Console.WriteLine("You lose")
                Console.ReadLine()
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to hit or stick?")
                answer = Console.ReadLine
                If answer = "hit" Then
                    value = (3 * Rnd()) + 1
                    value2 = (11 * Rnd()) + 1
                    If value2 = 1 Then
                        royal = "2"
                    ElseIf value2 = 2 Then
                        royal = "3"
                    ElseIf value2 = 3 Then
                        royal = "4"
                    ElseIf value2 = 4 Then
                        royal = "5"
                    ElseIf value2 = 5 Then
                        royal = "6"
                    ElseIf value2 = 6 Then
                        royal = "7"
                    ElseIf value2 = 7 Then
                        royal = "8"
                    ElseIf value2 = 8 Then
                        royal = "9"
                    ElseIf value2 = 9 Then
                        royal = "10"
                    ElseIf value2 = 10 Then
                        royal = "jack"
                    ElseIf value2 = 11 Then
                        royal = "queen"
                    ElseIf value2 = 12 Then
                        royal = "king"
                    End If
                    If value = 1 Then
                        suit = "hearts"
                    ElseIf value = 2 Then
                        suit = "diamonds"
                    ElseIf value = 3 Then
                        suit = "spades"
                    ElseIf value = 4 Then
                        suit = "clubs"
                    End If


                    Console.WriteLine("your card is the {0} of {1}", royal, suit)
                    card4 = cards(value, value2)
                    Console.ReadKey()
                    total = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4
                    If total > 21 Then
                        Console.WriteLine("You lose")
                        Console.ReadLine()
                    Else
                        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to hit or stick?")
                        answer = Console.ReadLine
                        If answer = "hit" Then
                            value = (3 * Rnd()) + 1
                            value2 = (11 * Rnd()) + 1
                            If value2 = 1 Then
                                royal = "2"
                            ElseIf value2 = 2 Then
                                royal = "3"
                            ElseIf value2 = 3 Then
                                royal = "4"
                            ElseIf value2 = 4 Then
                                royal = "5"
                            ElseIf value2 = 5 Then
                                royal = "6"
                            ElseIf value2 = 6 Then
                                royal = "7"
                            ElseIf value2 = 7 Then
                                royal = "8"
                            ElseIf value2 = 8 Then
                                royal = "9"
                            ElseIf value2 = 9 Then
                                royal = "10"
                            ElseIf value2 = 10 Then
                                royal = "jack"
                            ElseIf value2 = 11 Then
                                royal = "queen"
                            ElseIf value2 = 12 Then
                                royal = "king"
                            End If
                            If value = 1 Then
                                suit = "hearts"
                            ElseIf value = 2 Then
                                suit = "diamonds"
                            ElseIf value = 3 Then
                                suit = "spades"
                            ElseIf value = 4 Then
                                suit = "clubs"
                            End If

                            Console.WriteLine("your card is the {0} of {1}", royal, suit)
                            card5 = cards(value, value2)
                            Console.ReadKey()
                            total = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4 + card5
                            If total > 21 Then
                                Console.WriteLine("You lose")
                                Console.ReadLine()
                            Else
                                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to hit or stick?")
                                answer = Console.ReadLine
                                If answer = "hit" Then
                                    value = (3 * Rnd()) + 1
                                    value2 = (11 * Rnd()) + 1
                                    If value2 = 1 Then
                                        royal = "2"
                                    ElseIf value2 = 2 Then
                                        royal = "3"
                                    ElseIf value2 = 3 Then
                                        royal = "4"
                                    ElseIf value2 = 4 Then
                                        royal = "5"
                                    ElseIf value2 = 5 Then
                                        royal = "6"
                                    ElseIf value2 = 6 Then
                                        royal = "7"
                                    ElseIf value2 = 7 Then
                                        royal = "8"
                                    ElseIf value2 = 8 Then
                                        royal = "9"
                                    ElseIf value2 = 9 Then
                                        royal = "10"
                                    ElseIf value2 = 10 Then
                                        royal = "jack"
                                    ElseIf value2 = 11 Then
                                        royal = "queen"
                                    ElseIf value2 = 12 Then
                                        royal = "king"
                                    End If
                                    If value = 1 Then
                                        suit = "hearts"
                                    ElseIf value = 2 Then
                                        suit = "diamonds"
                                    ElseIf value = 3 Then
                                        suit = "spades"
                                    ElseIf value = 4 Then
                                        suit = "clubs"
                                    End If


                                    Console.WriteLine("your card is the {0} of {1}", royal, suit)
                                    card6 = cards(value, value2)
                                    Console.ReadKey()
                                    total = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4 + card5 + card6
                                    If total > 21 Then
                                        Console.WriteLine("You lose")
                                        Console.ReadLine()
                                    Else
                                        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to hit or stick?")
                                        answer = Console.ReadLine
                                        If answer = "hit" Then
                                            value = (3 * Rnd()) + 1
                                            value2 = (11 * Rnd()) + 1
                                            If value2 = 1 Then
                                                royal = "2"
                                            ElseIf value2 = 2 Then
                                                royal = "3"
                                            ElseIf value2 = 3 Then
                                                royal = "4"
                                            ElseIf value2 = 4 Then
                                                royal = "5"
                                            ElseIf value2 = 5 Then
                                                royal = "6"
                                            ElseIf value2 = 6 Then
                                                royal = "7"
                                            ElseIf value2 = 7 Then
                                                royal = "8"
                                            ElseIf value2 = 8 Then
                                                royal = "9"
                                            ElseIf value2 = 9 Then
                                                royal = "10"
                                            ElseIf value2 = 10 Then
                                                royal = "jack"
                                            ElseIf value2 = 11 Then
                                                royal = "queen"
                                            ElseIf value2 = 12 Then
                                                royal = "king"
                                            End If
                                            If value = 1 Then
                                                suit = "hearts"
                                            ElseIf value = 2 Then
                                                suit = "diamonds"
                                            ElseIf value = 3 Then
                                                suit = "spades"
                                            ElseIf value = 4 Then
                                                suit = "clubs"
                                            End If

                                            Console.WriteLine("your card is the {0} of {1}", royal, suit)
                                            card7 = cards(value, value2)
                                            Console.ReadKey()
                                            total = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4 + card5 + card6 + card7
                                        ElseIf answer = "stick" Then
                                            Console.WriteLine("your final score is {0}", total)
                                            Console.ReadLine()

                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If




    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You should back up and use a Class for the Card and some sort of collection for the Deck.  Picking random cards out of an array will result in dupes (2 people dealt the same card).  [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26512850/1070452) for an example

Comment: you should definitely learn how to use loops when programming such things. The code is neither readable nor easily extendable.

Comment: I'd recommend posting it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Codereview is for reviewing working code, not design/implementation/code issues @Kai

Comment: @Plutonix my suggestion was after he fixed his problem and changed and implemented some loops he could post it on codereview for approval.

Answer (score 0):

Use a rule like: Aces are worth 11, unless the total exceeds 21, then they are worth 1. You have to recalculate the total for each ace in the hand until the total is less then or equal to 21. This might not be a truly optimal strategy, but good enough for learning how to code.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember is that THERE IS NO "CHOICE" to count an ace as 1 or 11. It is strictly determined by the hand. Count all aces as 1. Then, if the hand contains one or more aces, and totals less than 12, add 10. That's it. Only one ace can ever be counted as 11, and only when it MUST be.

The really tricky part of programming blackjack is to remember that you need to keep track of the hand total and an extra bit of info to indicate if the total is "soft" or not (if you added the 10 above, it's soft).