# Use Paint event inside of a class

Tags: vb.net, class, visual-studio-2012, event-handling

I'm trying to create a function within a class that will draw a playing card. I'm still getting to grips with Drawing in Winforms, so bear with me.

The basic class so far looks like this:

```
Public Class Card
    Public Suit As Char
    Public Value As String
    Public Sub New(_Suit As Char, _Value As String)
        Suit = _Suit
        Value = _Value
    End Sub
    Public Sub Draw()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Within the Card class, I want to create a sub Draw which draws a white rectangle, adds the number, suit symbol, etc. I've got the code that will draw a white rectangle, but I don't know how to adapt it to use inside a class. All I have is this eventhandler:

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim p As Pen
    p = New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
    Dim rekt = New Rectangle(New Point(10, 10), New Size(90, 126))
    Me.CreateGraphics.DrawRectangle(p, rekt)
    CreateGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rekt)
End Sub
```

This creates a white rectangle automatically when the Form loads. When I C&P the code in this eventhandler into the Draw function, it doesn't work, because CreateGraphics isn't a member of the Card class.

Is there a simple fix for this, or should I be approaching this fundamentally diferently?

Comment: Unless this is learning excercise you could just [store the deck in an imagelist and load them from there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26532939/1070452).  CreateGraphics is almost never the right thing to do.  Use the graphics object supplied by the paint event.  Pass e.Graphics to Card.Draw and the card can draw itself

Comment: ...also for a generic Card class, they would have a Suit, Rank and Value.  In BlackJack and Baccarat (and others like Euchre) some cards will have a different value than the Rank

Comment: I don't understand how value and rank could be different things, but I'm not currently planning to program a game where I'd need to worry about that :).

Comment: Using images makes a lot more sense, I was just curious to see if programmatically-drawn cards are doable. Could you explain in more detail what you mean by using the graphics object, and passing e.Graphics? I don't really understand what that means in terms of code.

Comment: Well, in blackjack a Jack is worth 10 but the Rank is still 11/J; in Baccarat it is still a Jack but has a value of 0. look at the arguments passed in the paint event: `e As PaintEventArgs` it supplies you with a graphics object

Comment: Sorry, I'm gonna need you to be more explicit. What should I put in my code to make it so that I can use Graphics in Card.Draw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier to [load pre-done images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532939/1070452) from an imagelist, so the the appropriate image can just be another `Card` property.  Otherwise you could get into things like drawing Heart and Club shapes (or changing fonts to use WebDings or perhaps a [CardFace font](http://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Card_Characters.htm) or also drawing a bitmap of the suit symbol).

Your cards can draw themselves though, but you want to use the `Graphics` object which Windows provides in the paint event:

```
myCard = New Card("Diamonds", 6)

Private Sub pb_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles pb.Paint
    myCard.Draw(e.Graphics)
End Sub
```

`e` is the `PaintEventArgs` passed to you in the paint event.  Its a class and one of the members is a `Graphics` object.  `Card.Draw()` method:

```
Public Sub Draw(g As Graphics)

    Dim br As Brush = Brushes.Black
    If Suit.ToLowerInvariant = "hearts" Or Suit.ToLowerInvariant = "diamonds" Then
        br = Brushes.Red
    End If

    Using p As New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
        Dim rekt = New Rectangle(New Point(10, 10), New Size(90, 126))
        g.DrawRectangle(p, rekt)
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rekt)

        Using f As New Font("Verdana", 16, FontStyle.Bold)
            g.DrawString(Rank.ToString & " " & Suit(0), f, br, New Point(12, 12))
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Output (very crude!):

[image]

Notice also that I am disposing of the `Pen` created.  And in case it needs explaining `Suit(0)` indicates the first character of the string.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! I'll try this out later.

Comment: I decided to go the image route you suggested, as it was getting unnecessarily complex. But this was still really helpful.