# how to generate random pictures in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to get a random picture generator for a card. I am trying to use an array to generate five different pictures for 5 picture boxes. I am currently using if statements but would like to use Arrays. This is my code so far,

```
Dim rndnumber As Integer

Randomize()

rndnumber = Int(Rnd() * 52) + 1
If ListBox1.Items.Contains(rndnumber) Then
    rndnumber = Int(Rnd() * 52) + 1
End If
ListBox1.Items.Add(rndnumber)

If rndnumber = 1 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources.aceclubs
ElseIf rndnumber = 2 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources.acediamonds
ElseIf rndnumber = 3 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources.acehearts
ElseIf rndnumber = 4 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources.acespades
ElseIf rndnumber = 5 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._2clubs
ElseIf rndnumber = 6 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._2diamonds
ElseIf rndnumber = 7 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._2hearts
ElseIf rndnumber = 8 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._2spades
ElseIf rndnumber = 9 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._3clubs
ElseIf rndnumber = 10 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._3diamonds
ElseIf rndnumber = 11 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._3hearts
ElseIf rndnumber = 12 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._3spades
ElseIf rndnumber = 13 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._4clubs
ElseIf rndnumber = 14 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._4diamonds
ElseIf rndnumber = 15 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._4hearts
ElseIf rndnumber = 16 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._4spades
ElseIf rndnumber = 17 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._5clubs
ElseIf rndnumber = 18 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._5diamonds
ElseIf rndnumber = 19 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._5hearts
ElseIf rndnumber = 20 Then
    Me.playerhand1.Image = My.Resources._5spades
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What problem you encounter when you do that? And it is as you have noticed, it is much better to use array or Dictionary to get rid of your multiple if-else statements

Comment: the problem is that I would like it is so 5 different picture boxes get a different image. so far, all that code is just for one picture box.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26532939/1070452) may be of interest  it would be easier to read the images from an ImageList you could reference them by a key created from the suit and rank

Comment: I see, then I suggest you to make a `while` loop condition and test if your newly picked number is already exist. When the number of unique number is 5, then you escape the while loop

Comment: well to be more specific, I am trying to make a game of blackjack for a project. Will that work for this game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking to your random generator, something like this will do:

```
Dim rndnumber As Integer
Randomize()
Dim rndNumberList As New List(Of Integer)
Do
    rndnumber = Int(Rnd() * 52) + 1
    If Not rndNumberList.Contains(rndnumber) Then
        rndNumberList.Add(rndnumber)
    End If
Loop Until rndNumberList.Count >= 5 'Basically you loop until you find 5 unique number
```

Basically you loop until you find 5 unique numbers

But better still I think is to make a list which consists of number 1-52, and every time you loop, you take that element from the list, making it only having -1 (like 52 to 51) element. Then repeat the process from 1 to the number of cards left (-1 from the previous try). This way, you ensure that you will never get two same numbers repeated (you will only pick one number once).

Side Note: maybe you want to start your index from 0 too (ends at 51), since in VB.Net the index start from 0

Comment: just to make sure, will this work with 5 different picture boxes. if yes, how will I make it to work with the 5 different picture boxes.

Comment: @k.low Yes, because what it does is simply get 5 random numbers and put them to List. It is up to you what to do with the numbers in the list. For instance, from the 5 numbers in the list, you could use your array/dictionary-to-be (currently if-else) you could firstly get 5 images you want to put in your 5 picture boxes. Then you use for loop to put the 5 images, each image in 1 pictureBox or just put them with 5 statement, since there are only five. But you get the idea...

Comment: Ok just one last question, how would I mention the 5 numbers separately for the picture boxes.

Comment: @k.low the picture box receive image, not number. you have to first convert the list of number (the name in the code `rndNumberList`) to the list of image (let say, the name is `imageList`) by using your current if-else statement (don't assign directly the image to picture box, put in the `imageList` first). Then after you get the `imageList`, you could do: `Me.playerhand1.Image = imageList(0) Me.playerhand2.Image = imageList(1) Me.playerhand3.Image = imageList(2) ...` and so on. Note that the index starts from `0` not `1`