# VB Classic Poker. Detecting a winning hand using modulo

Tags: vb.net, modulo, poker

I need to create a poker game in vb as work for my class using mod13 for each suite to evaluate the winning hand... but I am at lost here. I just can't get how to use modulo.

I really need an hint how to do it.  (this is what I have coded so far....)

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Cards(4) As PictureBox
    Dim Hand(4) As Integer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Creat_poker()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Creat_Poker_interface()
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To pic.GetUpperBound(0)
            Cards(i) = New PictureBox

            With Cards(i)
                .Visible = True
                .Width = 130
                .Height = 200
                .Left = 20 + (i * 160)
                .Top = 20
                .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
                .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

            End With
            Me.Controls.Add(pic(i))


            AddHandler Cards(i).Click, AddressOf CardsSelection

        Next
    End Sub



    Private Sub cmdNewGame_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdNewGame.Click
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim hasard As New Random
        For i = 0 To main.GetUpperBound(0)
            Hand(i) = hasard.Next(52)

        Next

        For i = 0 To main.GetUpperBound(0)
            Cards(i).Image = imaCards.Images(Hand(i))
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I would not even *try* to write a card game using procedural code.  Card games cry out for classes: Card, Deck, Player, House, Game.  Your code is no where near the point it needs to evaluate hands.  [This answer may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26532939/1070452) ... and linq would be very useful in detecting hand ranks

Comment: (maybe it me lack of experience that was not clear or maybe that my English is not good enough but ... ) 

Thank for your reply. I am using "event code" I use a button to start the game. Check-boxes for the cards I want to hold and as well as an other buttons for the purpose of making the game progress after selection the cards I want to keep or simply make the "round" Finish if I don't keep one. 

Also there will be an numeric up down to bet bet money.

An a quit button to exit the game(program)

Comment: also it a classic video poker style so, so the minimal hand to have in  order to win is either having a pair jack minimum or better.