# Visual Basic Windows Form - Help Loading picture corresponding to numerical value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hello i am trying to make a texas hold'em style game and im at the point where i filled an array with numbers 1-52 randomly assorted.  I first pull the value from the first index of the array and have the corresponding card picture be set to a picturebox value.  I have saved the 52 card .png files in my resources as well. These pictures are also saved with their names as 1.png, 2.png, 3.png.... etc depending the suit and value.

I am sorting the values as 1-13 spades (2-ace), 14-26 hearts, 27-39 diamonds, 40-52 clubs.

I also just saw i should probably use a global counter to keep track of the deck position.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Deal As MsgBoxResult
    Dim CardDeck As New Random
    Dim Counter As Integer = 1
    Dim CardCount(52) As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

        Deal = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to start a Game?", "Texas Holde'em", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        ShuffleDeck()
        CalculateFirst3Cards()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ShuffleDeck()

        If Deal = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            For num As Integer = 1 To CardCount.Length - 1
                Dim DeckValue As Integer = CardDeck.Next(1, 52)
                CardCount(Counter) = DeckValue
                Counter += 1
            Next
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub CalculateFirst3Cards()
        Dim counter As Integer = 1
        For num As Integer = 1 To 3
            Dim hold As Integer = CardCount(counter)
            Dim hold1 As String = Convert.ToString(hold)
            River1.Image = My.Resources.

            counter += 1
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You are writing bad code, google "vb.net random shuffle".  Use My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject() to retrieve the image.

Comment: You are going to have a very hard time evaluating hands using a simple array for the cards.  Better would be a Card Class with Suit, Rank and Value properties, from which the card image could be determined.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26532939