# Blackjack playing cards issue

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have written a Blackjack game/program in VB.NET. So far I have coded the playing card images to show and hide. For example, the program randomly draws  numbers from 1 - 13 (Ace - King) and displays those random numbers in a label. If a 1 is in the label an image of an Ace in a picture box will become visible.

Here is my code for referencing:

```
Public Class frmBlackJack
Public Counter As Integer = 0

Private Sub btnDrawCard_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDrawCard.Click
    Randomize()
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Dim Card1 As Integer
    Dim Card2 As Integer
    Dim Card3 As Integer
    Dim Card4 As Integer
    Dim Card5 As Integer


    If lblCard1.Text = "1" Then
        picCard1Ace.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "1" Then
        picCard2Ace.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "1" Then
        picCard3Ace.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "1" Then
        picCard4Ace.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "1" Then
        picCard5Ace.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "2" Then
        picCard1Two.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "2" Then
        picCard2Two.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "2" Then
        picCard3Two.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "2" Then
        picCard4Two.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "2" Then
        picCard5Two.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "3" Then
        picCard1Three.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "3" Then
        picCard2Three.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "3" Then
        picCard3Three.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "3" Then
        picCard4Three.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "3" Then
        picCard5Three.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "4" Then
        picCard1Four.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "4" Then
        picCard2Four.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "4" Then
        picCard3Four.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "4" Then
        picCard4Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "4" Then
        picCard5Four.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "5" Then
        picCard1Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "5" Then
        picCard2Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "5" Then
        picCard3Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "5" Then
        picCard4Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "5" Then
        picCard5Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "6" Then
        picCard1Six.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "6" Then
        picCard2Six.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "6" Then
        picCard3Six.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "6" Then
        picCard4Six.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "6" Then
        picCard5Six.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "7" Then
        picCard1Seven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "7" Then
        picCard2Seven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "7" Then
        picCard3Seven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "7" Then
        picCard4Seven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "7" Then
        picCard5Seven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "8" Then
        picCard1Eight.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "8" Then
        picCard2Eight.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "8" Then
        picCard3Eight.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "8" Then
        picCard4Eight.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "8" Then
        picCard5Eight.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "9" Then
        picCard1Nine.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "9" Then
        picCard2Nine.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "9" Then
        picCard3Nine.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "9" Then
        picCard4Nine.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "9" Then
        picCard5Nine.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "10" Then
        picCard1Ten.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "10" Then
        picCard2Ten.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "10" Then
        picCard3Ten.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "10" Then
        picCard4Ten.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "10" Then
        picCard5Ten.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "11" Then
        picCard1Eleven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "11" Then
        picCard2Eleven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "11" Then
        picCard3Eleven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "11" Then
        picCard4Eleven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "11" Then
        picCard5Eleven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "12" Then
        picCard1Queen.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "12" Then
        picCard2Queen.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "12" Then
        picCard3Queen.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "12" Then
        picCard4Queen.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "12" Then
        picCard5Queen.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "13" Then
        picCard1King.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "13" Then
        picCard2King.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "13" Then
        picCard3King.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "13" Then
        picCard4King.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "13" Then
        picCard5King.Visible = True
    End If

    If Counter >= 1 Then
        btnCheckScore.Enabled = True
    End If
    If Counter = 1 Then
        Card1 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
        lblCard1.Text = Card1
        lblCard1.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter = 2 Then
        Card2 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
        lblCard2.Text = Card2
        lblCard2.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter = 3 Then
        Card3 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
        lblCard3.Text = Card3
        lblCard3.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter = 4 Then
        Card4 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
        lblCard4.Text = Card4
        lblCard4.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter = 5 Then
        Card5 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
        lblCard5.Text = Card5
        lblCard5.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter > 5 Then
        MsgBox("You can't draw anymore cards!")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmBlackJack_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ComputerCard1 As Integer
    Dim ComputerCard2 As Integer
    Dim ComputerCard3 As Integer

    ComputerCard1 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
    ComputerCard2 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
    ComputerCard3 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)

    lblComputerCard1.Text = ComputerCard1
    lblComputerCard2.Text = ComputerCard2
    lblComputerCard3.Text = ComputerCard3

    lblComputerScore.Visible = False
    lblYourScore.Visible = False

    btnCheckScore.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub btnCheckScore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheckScore.Click
    Dim PlayerSum As Integer
    Dim ComputerSum As Integer

    Dim youWonTitle As String = "You Won!"
    Dim youWonMsg As String = "Great work! Play again?"
    Dim youLostTitle As String = "You Lost!"
    Dim youLostMsg As String = "Better luck next time! Play again?"
    Dim youDrewTitle As String = "You Drew"
    Dim youDrewMsg As String = "That was close! Play again?"

    Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo

    lblComputerCard1.Visible = True
    lblComputerCard2.Visible = True
    lblComputerCard3.Visible = True

    btnDrawCard.Enabled = False

    If Counter < 1 Then
        PlayerSum = Val(lblCard1.Text)
        lblPLayerScore.Text = PlayerSum
        lblPLayerScore.Visible = True
        lblYourScore.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter > 1 Then
        PlayerSum = Val(lblCard1.Text) + Val(lblCard2.Text)
        lblPLayerScore.Text = PlayerSum
        lblPLayerScore.Visible = True
        lblYourScore.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter > 2 Then
        PlayerSum = Val(lblCard1.Text) + Val(lblCard2.Text) + Val(lblCard3.Text)
        lblPLayerScore.Text = PlayerSum
        lblPLayerScore.Visible = True
        lblYourScore.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter > 3 Then
        PlayerSum = Val(lblCard1.Text) + Val(lblCard2.Text) + Val(lblCard3.Text) + Val(lblCard4.Text)
        lblPLayerScore.Text = PlayerSum
        lblPLayerScore.Visible = True
        lblYourScore.Visible = True
    End If
    If Counter > 4 Then
        PlayerSum = Val(lblCard1.Text) + Val(lblCard2.Text) + Val(lblCard3.Text) + Val(lblCard4.Text) + Val(lblCard5.Text)
        lblPLayerScore.Text = PlayerSum
        lblPLayerScore.Visible = True
        lblYourScore.Visible = True
    End If

    ComputerSum = Val(lblComputerCard1.Text) + Val(lblComputerCard2.Text) + Val(lblComputerCard3.Text)
    lblComputerTotal.Text = ComputerSum
    lblComputerScore.Visible = True
    lblComputerTotal.Visible = True

    If lblCard1.Text = 1 Then

    End If

    If PlayerSum < 21 And PlayerSum > ComputerSum Then
        Dim responseYouWon = MsgBox(youWonMsg, style, youWonTitle)
        If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum > 21 And PlayerSum < 21 Then
        Dim responseYouWon = MsgBox(youWonMsg, style, youWonTitle)
        If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum > 21 And ComputerSum < 21 Then
        Dim responseYouWon = MsgBox(youWonMsg, style, youWonTitle)
        If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf PlayerSum = 21 And ComputerSum > 21 Then
        Dim responseYouWon = MsgBox(youWonMsg, style, youWonTitle)
        If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf PlayerSum = 21 And ComputerSum < 21 Then
        Dim responseYouWon = MsgBox(youWonMsg, style, youWonTitle)
        If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum < 21 And ComputerSum > PlayerSum Then
        Dim responseYouLost = MsgBox(youLostMsg, style, youLostTitle)
        If responseYouLost = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf PlayerSum > 21 And ComputerSum < 21 Then
        Dim responseYouLost = MsgBox(youLostMsg, style, youLostTitle)
        If responseYouLost = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum = 21 And PlayerSum <> 21 Then
        Dim responseYouLost = MsgBox(youLostMsg, style, youLostTitle)
        If responseYouLost = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If
    End If

    If lblCard1.Text = "1" Then
        picCard1Ace.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "1" Then
        picCard2Ace.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "1" Then
        picCard3Ace.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "1" Then
        picCard4Ace.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "1" Then
        picCard5Ace.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "2" Then
        picCard1Two.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "2" Then
        picCard2Two.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "2" Then
        picCard3Two.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "2" Then
        picCard4Two.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "2" Then
        picCard5Two.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "3" Then
        picCard1Three.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "3" Then
        picCard2Three.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "3" Then
        picCard3Three.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "3" Then
        picCard4Three.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "3" Then
        picCard5Three.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "4" Then
        picCard1Four.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "4" Then
        picCard2Four.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "4" Then
        picCard3Four.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "4" Then
        picCard4Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "4" Then
        picCard5Four.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "5" Then
        picCard1Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "5" Then
        picCard2Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "5" Then
        picCard3Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "5" Then
        picCard4Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "5" Then
        picCard5Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "6" Then
        picCard1Six.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "6" Then
        picCard2Six.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "6" Then
        picCard3Six.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "6" Then
        picCard4Six.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "6" Then
        picCard5Six.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "7" Then
        picCard1Seven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "7" Then
        picCard2Seven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "7" Then
        picCard3Seven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "7" Then
        picCard4Seven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "7" Then
        picCard5Seven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "8" Then
        picCard1Eight.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "8" Then
        picCard2Eight.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "8" Then
        picCard3Eight.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "8" Then
        picCard4Eight.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "8" Then
        picCard5Eight.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "9" Then
        picCard1Nine.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "9" Then
        picCard2Nine.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "9" Then
        picCard3Nine.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "9" Then
        picCard4Nine.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "9" Then
        picCard5Nine.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "10" Then
        picCard1Ten.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "10" Then
        picCard2Ten.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "10" Then
        picCard3Ten.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "10" Then
        picCard4Ten.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "10" Then
        picCard5Ten.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "11" Then
        picCard1Eleven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "11" Then
        picCard2Eleven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "11" Then
        picCard3Eleven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "11" Then
        picCard4Eleven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "11" Then
        picCard5Eleven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "12" Then
        picCard1Queen.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "12" Then
        picCard2Queen.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "12" Then
        picCard3Queen.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "12" Then
        picCard4Queen.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "12" Then
        picCard5Queen.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard1.Text = "13" Then
        picCard1King.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard2.Text = "13" Then
        picCard2King.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard3.Text = "13" Then
        picCard3King.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard4.Text = "13" Then
        picCard4King.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblCard5.Text = "13" Then
        picCard5King.Visible = True
    End If


    If lblComputerCard1.Text = "1" Then
        picComCard1Ace.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard2.Text = "1" Then
        picComCard2Ace.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard3.Text = "1" Then
        picComCard3Ace.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard1.Text = "2" Then
        picComCard1Two.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard2.Text = "2" Then
        picComCard2Two.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard3.Text = "2" Then
        picComCard3Two.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard1.Text = "3" Then
        picComCard1Three.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard2.Text = "3" Then
        picComCard2Three.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard3.Text = "3" Then
        picComCard3Three.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard1.Text = "4" Then
        picComCard1Four.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard2.Text = "4" Then
        picComCard2Four.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard3.Text = "4" Then
        picComCard3Four.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard1.Text = "5" Then
        picComCard1Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard2.Text = "5" Then
        picComCard2Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard3.Text = "5" Then
        picComCard3Five.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard1.Text = "6" Then
        picComCard1Six.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard2.Text = "6" Then
        picComCard2Six.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard3.Text = "6" Then
        picComCard3Six.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard1.Text = "7" Then
        picComCard1Seven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard2.Text = "7" Then
        picComCard2Seven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard3.Text = "7" Then
        picComCard3Seven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard1.Text = "8" Then
        piComCard1Eight.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard2.Text = "8" Then
        piComCard2Eight.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard3.Text = "8" Then
        piComCard3Eight.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard1.Text = "9" Then
        picComCard1Nine.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard2.Text = "9" Then
        picComCard2Nine.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard3.Text = "9" Then
        picComCard3Nine.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard1.Text = "10" Then
        picComCard1Ten.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard2.Text = "10" Then
        picComCard2Ten.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard3.Text = "10" Then
        picComCard3Ten.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard1.Text = "11" Then
        picComCard1Eleven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard2.Text = "11" Then
        picComCard2Eleven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard3.Text = "11" Then
        picComCard3Eleven.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard1.Text = "12" Then
        picComCard1Queen.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard2.Text = "12" Then
        picComCard2Queen.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard3.Text = "12" Then
        picComCard3Queen.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard1.Text = "13" Then
        picComCard1King.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard2.Text = "13" Then
        picComCard2King.Visible = True
    End If
    If lblComputerCard3.Text = "13" Then
        picComCard3King.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnPlayAgain_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlayAgain.Click
    Dim ComputerCard1 As Integer
    Dim ComputerCard2 As Integer
    Dim ComputerCard3 As Integer
    lblComputerCard1.Visible = False
    lblComputerCard2.Visible = False
    lblComputerCard3.Visible = False
    lblComputerCard1.Text = ""
    lblComputerCard2.Text = ""
    lblComputerCard3.Text = ""

    lblCard1.Visible = False
    lblCard2.Visible = False
    lblCard3.Visible = False
    lblCard4.Visible = False
    lblCard5.Visible = False
    lblCard1.Text = ""
    lblCard2.Text = ""
    lblCard3.Text = ""
    lblCard4.Text = ""
    lblCard5.Text = ""
    Counter = 0

    ComputerCard1 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
    ComputerCard2 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
    ComputerCard3 = (10 * Rnd() + 1)
    lblComputerCard1.Text = ComputerCard1
    lblComputerCard2.Text = ComputerCard2
    lblComputerCard3.Text = ComputerCard3

    btnDrawCard.Enabled = True
    btnCheckScore.Enabled = True

    lblComputerTotal.Text = ""
    lblPLayerScore.Text = ""
    lblComputerTotal.Visible = False
    lblPLayerScore.Visible = False
    lblComputerScore.Visible = False
    lblYourScore.Visible = False

    picCard1Ace.Visible = False
    picCard2Ace.Visible = False
    picCard3Ace.Visible = False
    picCard4Ace.Visible = False
    picCard5Ace.Visible = False
    picCard1Two.Visible = False
    picCard2Two.Visible = False
    picCard3Two.Visible = False
    picCard4Two.Visible = False
    picCard5Two.Visible = False
    picCard1Three.Visible = False
    picCard2Three.Visible = False
    picCard3Three.Visible = False
    picCard4Three.Visible = False
    picCard5Three.Visible = False
    picCard1Four.Visible = False
    picCard2Four.Visible = False
    picCard3Four.Visible = False
    picCard4Four.Visible = False
    picCard5Four.Visible = False
    picCard1Five.Visible = False
    picCard2Five.Visible = False
    picCard3Five.Visible = False
    picCard4Five.Visible = False
    picCard5Five.Visible = False
    picCard1Six.Visible = False
    picCard2Six.Visible = False
    picCard3Six.Visible = False
    picCard4Six.Visible = False
    picCard5Six.Visible = False
    picCard1Seven.Visible = False
    picCard2Seven.Visible = False
    picCard3Seven.Visible = False
    picCard4Seven.Visible = False
    picCard5Seven.Visible = False
    picCard1Eight.Visible = False
    picCard2Eight.Visible = False
    picCard3Eight.Visible = False
    picCard4Eight.Visible = False
    picCard5Eight.Visible = False
    picCard1Nine.Visible = False
    picCard2Nine.Visible = False
    picCard3Nine.Visible = False
    picCard4Nine.Visible = False
    picCard5Nine.Visible = False
    picCard1Ten.Visible = False
    picCard2Ten.Visible = False
    picCard3Ten.Visible = False
    picCard4Ten.Visible = False
    picCard5Ten.Visible = False
    picCard1Queen.Visible = False
    picCard2Queen.Visible = False
    picCard3Queen.Visible = False
    picCard4Queen.Visible = False
    picCard5Queen.Visible = False
    picCard1King.Visible = False
    picCard2King.Visible = False
    picCard3King.Visible = False
    picCard4King.Visible = False
    picCard5King.Visible = False

    picComCard1Ace.Visible = False
    picComCard2Ace.Visible = False
    picComCard3Ace.Visible = False
    picComCard1Two.Visible = False
    picComCard2Two.Visible = False
    picComCard3Two.Visible = False
    picComCard1Three.Visible = False
    picComCard2Three.Visible = False
    picComCard3Three.Visible = False
    picComCard1Four.Visible = False
    picComCard2Four.Visible = False
    picComCard3Four.Visible = False
    picComCard1Five.Visible = False
    picComCard2Five.Visible = False
    picComCard3Five.Visible = False
    picComCard1Six.Visible = False
    picComCard2Six.Visible = False
    picComCard3Six.Visible = False
    picComCard1Seven.Visible = False
    picComCard2Seven.Visible = False
    picComCard3Seven.Visible = False
    piComCard1Eight.Visible = False
    piComCard2Eight.Visible = False
    piComCard3Eight.Visible = False
    picComCard1Nine.Visible = False
    picComCard2Nine.Visible = False
    picComCard3Nine.Visible = False
    picComCard1Ten.Visible = False
    picComCard2Ten.Visible = False
    picComCard3Ten.Visible = False
    picComCard1Eleven.Visible = False
    picComCard2Eleven.Visible = False
    picComCard3Eleven.Visible = False
    picComCard1Queen.Visible = False
    picComCard2Queen.Visible = False
    picComCard3Queen.Visible = False
    picComCard1King.Visible = False
    picComCard2King.Visible = False
    picComCard3King.Visible = False

    btnCheckScore.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub btnQuit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnQuit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub StartGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartGameToolStripMenuItem.Click
    btnDrawCard.PerformClick()

End Sub

Private Sub QuitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles QuitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Here are some images of the problem:

[image: Blackjack Issue Image 1]

[image: Blackjack Issue Image 2]

Comment: What is your problem? Also, you should (almost) never seed the PRNG more than once, so just remove the `Randomize` call from your event handler and instead move it to the Form's constructor.

Comment: Picking a random number from 1-13 is nothing like drawing from a deck because there is nothing to constrain it from picking any card more than once.  You need to create a deck like object - an array of 1-52 will do, then put them in random order.  When you draw one, remove it from the deck so it cant be used again.  A 'Stack' would be a good collection for this.  Using classes makes this much much easier. See [shuffle and deal cards one at a time to players?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26532939/1070452)  for an example