# Visual Basic. How to paint a card and click on it?

Tags: vb.net

I draw the card on a form but when i click on it nothing happens. Why?

This is a simple example to figure out how to do it

```
Public Class Form1

Private WithEvents Carta As Card

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Carta = New Card("s", "5")
    AddHandler Carta.Paint, AddressOf Carta.Card_Paint
    AddHandler Carta.Click, AddressOf Carta.Card_Click
    AddHandler Carta.MouseClick, AddressOf Carta.Card_MouseClick


End Sub

End Class
```

I create Card Class

```
Friend Class Card
Inherits Control

Private suit As String
Private face As String
Private card_image As Bitmap

Public Sub New(ByVal s As String, ByVal f As String)
    suit = s
    face = f
    card_image = New Bitmap(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Cards", s & f & ".gif"))
    Card_Paint()
End Sub

Public Sub Card_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    MsgBox(suit & face)

End Sub

Public Sub Card_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
    MsgBox(suit & face)
End Sub

Public Sub Card_Paint()
    Form1.CreateGraphics.DrawImage(card_image, New Point(10, 30))
End Sub
End Class
```

When I Click on button card is correctly shown but if I click on it nothing happens!!! What is the error?

Comment: A) CreateGraphics is almost always the wrong way to paint/draw.  Use the Paint event or OnPaint method.  B) Your card class need not inherit control.  You could more easily use the class for the Suit, Rank and Value properties and use a button or picture box for displaying the image (which already know how to paint themselves). C) You rarely need to invoke the paint event - Windows does that for you when it is needed.  Use `Invalidate` to queue a Paint event.

Comment: ...also you almost certainly will want a Deck class to [create all cards and shuffle them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26532939/1070452).  Creating them one at a time from a button click will make it difficult to not repeat cards (once you add a random element to it).

Comment: Thank you Plutonix! But In the real application i have already created the the deck class where i create all cards and shuffle them with random. This was just an easy example to figure out the best way to show cards. I wanted to avoid using picture box...

Comment: But that is exactly what you are creating - the hard way.  First, card info (data) is inexorably glued to a UI element.  Second, creating controls is *expensive*.  In any given card game you know how many cards per player you need so you can create them at design time and just map cards to pictureboxes (also you code never adds the control to the controls collection so they are never shown).

Comment: Do I have to use Form1.controls.add(ThePictureBox)? Could you make me an example with just a card by writing the code? Thank you so much and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Well, `Form1`.anything opens another can of worms - default form instances.  Starting thinking in terms of layers or services: the deck of cards is the important thing in a card game. Showing them to the user is a different service, so the control and the data (collection of cards) are different things - but your code glues them together,  As such, your cards are not reusable (which in turn can cause the app to leak).  As for an example, I gave you a link 2 hours ago in the second comment

Comment: I didn't notice it. Thank you,

Comment: Regarding your actual issue, your `Paint` event handler is missing arguments: `Public Sub Card_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)`. Then you can draw using `e.Graphics.DrawImage(card_image, New Point(10, 30))`.