# Referencing resource images dynamically

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a Blackjack game and I'm having a rough time getting a picture of the cards without "hard coding" every single picture to values I'm passing it.

Current Code (not desired, but works):

```
Public Function Return_Card(CardVal As String, CardSuit As String) As Image
    If CardVal = "Ace" And CardSuit = "Clubs" Then
        Return My.Resources.AceOfClubs
    ElseIf CardVal = "Two" And CardSuit = "Clubs" Then
        Return My.Resources.TwoOfClubs
    ElseIf CardVal = "Three" And CardSuit = "Clubs" Then
        Return My.Resources.ThreeOfClubs
    ' Need the other 49 cards to complete deck
    End If
End Function
```

Desired Code:

```
Public Function Return_Card(CardVal As String, CardSuit As String) As Image
    ' Return any picture of a card based on what is being passed in CardVal and CardSuit
    Return My.Resources.CardValOfCardSuit
End Function
```

bump

Comment: For something like a card game you do not want to load them from resources over and over: each time you do it creates a new object which will cause your app to leak.  Load them from an ImageList or load them into an array from resources and use the same images over and over. [Rough Card Game](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532939/1070452)

Comment: Try not to get too detailed about how I'm storing my information, please. I am putting them into an array after creating the objects. @Plutonix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function Return_Card(CardVal As String, CardNum As String) As Image
    Return My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(CardVal + "Of" + CardNum)
End Function
```